# NHibernate. Records uniqueness

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, entity, unique

I have a class

```
abstract class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; private set; }
}
```

all my entities are inherited from it. In the case of `employee` entity that's impossible to have two employees with same passport-sn, and other identity-specific documents.

Howcome I disallow to put two employees with different `surrogate keys` and the same `passport number` to a database?

Is there any constraint in mapping?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the Unique constrain for passport

if you are using Fluent:

```
mapping.Id( employee => employee.Id);
mapping.Map(employee  => employee.passport ).Unique();
```

In your domain if all the entities inherits from Entity all of them will use a surrogate keys so you have to handle any other constrains

Comment: Ok. As far as I understand plain `xml` mapping gonna give the same result. So I should put the constraint on a property. Thanks!